# How to convert the time format into YYYY:MM:DD (without hour and minutes)

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to convert the time into a YYYY:MM:DD format. I have already truncated it from a timestamp format. However, with the trunc, I come up with this format (using Periscope):

[image]

Here is the date part of my query

[image: date code]

Comment: Do you want to save it in that format, or display it that way with a `SELECT`?

Comment: Im newish to sql so im not sure what the difference would be.

Comment: Save as in `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. These (and `DELETE`) alter the data stored in the database while `SELECT` reads from the database.

Comment: Also, you should post your sql code directly into the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: I know, I wish I could, however, the code is proprietary with my company.

Comment: That's when you create a generalized [mre]. Pasting a screenshot doesn't change that it is proprietary!

Comment: Ill be honest, I did not even think of that! I'll take a read, because that will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(your_date, 'yyyy:MM:dd')
```

Comment: Where would I put this in the query? Im newish to sql.

Comment: You can replace your screenshot part by this:
FORMAT(convert_timezone('UTC', 'Ameria/New_york', a.completed_at), 'yyyy:MM:dd') as completed_at_est,
FORMAT(convert_timezone('UTC', 'Ameria/New_york', a.reserved_at), 'yyyy:MM:dd') as reserved_at_est,